# C and OpenMP : nowait for loop in a do loop

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to minimize some function with may parameters `P` doing a Particle Swarm Optimization. What you need to know to help me, is that this procedure requires the computation of a particular function (that I call `foo`) for different indices `i` (each index is linked to a set of parameters `P`). The time that `foo` spend on each `i` is unpredictable and can vary a lot for different `i`. As soon as one `v[i]` has been computed, I'd like to start the computation of another one. This procedure stops when one `i` optimizes the function (it means that the corresponding set of parameters `P` has been found).

So I want to parallelize the computation with OpenMP. I do the following thing :

```
unsigned int N(5); 
unsigned int last_called(0);
std::vector<double> v(N,0.0);
std::vector<bool> busy(N,false);
std::vector<unsigned int> already_ran(N,0);
std::vector<unsigned int> to_run_in_priority(N);
for(unsigned int i(0);i<N;i++){
    to_run_in_priority[i]=i;
}
do{
#pramga omp parallel for nowait 
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(!busy[to_run_in_priority[i]]){
            busy[to_run_in_priority[i]]=true;
            already_ran[to_run_in_priority[i]]++;
            foo(v[to_run_in_priority[i]]);
            busy[to_run_in_priority[i]]=false;
        }
       /*update to_run_in_priority*/
    }
} while (/*condition*/)
```

If for instance I have 4 threads and N=5. The program will enter the for loop and lunch 4 threads. When the first `i` has been computed, it will lunch the 5th one. But then what will happen ?

Will the code continue, reach the `while` condition and enter again the `for` loop? If it does, as all the threads are busy, what will it do?

If what I want to do isn't clear, let me list I want :

- call `foo` for each `i` on a separate thread (`thread_numbers<N`)
- if some thread isn't running anymore, call again `foo` for some `i` (the next `i` that should run must be different than all other running `i` and it should be a `i` that has run less times than the others).
- do a loop on the two previous items until convergence criteria has been reached.

If i'm not clear enough, don't hesitate to ask precisions.

Comment: The `nowait` clause removes implicit barriers in the parallel for loops.  However, the way you have used it is useless since there is a barrier which can't be removed at the end of a parallel block.  Anyway, High Perfromance Mark's suggestion to use `schedule(dynamic)` seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments and answers, this is the solution i came up with.

```
unsigned int i(0);
unsigned int ip(0);
unsigned int N(10);
std::vector<bool> free(N,true)
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1) firstprivate(ip)
    for(unsigned int iter=0; iter<maxiter_; iter++){
#pragma omp critical
    {
        i++;
        ip = (i-1) % particle_.size();
        if(!free_[ip]){iter -= 1;}
    }
    if(free_[ip]){
        free_[ip]=false;
        if(ip<2){sleep(2);}
        else{ sleep(5);}
        free_[ip]=true;
    }
}
```

with the few tests I did, it seems to work. but does anyone have arguments against what I did?

Answer (score 4):

Abstracting somewhat from your code you seem to want to write something like

```
#pramga omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        v[i] = foo(i)
    }
```

but you are concerned that, because the computational effort of calls to `foo(i)` varies greatly, this simple approach will be poorly balanced if each thread simply gets a range of values of `i` on which to operate.

You are probably right to be concerned but I think, if my diagnosis is correct, that you are going the wrong way about balancing your program.  The wrong way that you are going about is to try to program the allocation of work to threads yourself.

Try this (pseudo-code) instead:

```
#pramga omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,10)
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        v[i] = foo(i)
    }
```

Notice the introduction of the `schedule` clause, in this case with parameters `dynamic` and `10`.  This directs the run-time to hand out bunches of values of `i`, 10 elements at a time, to individual threads.  Depending on the distribution of run-time for each value of `i`, and of the magnitude of `N` this may be sufficient to balance the load.

Then again, it may not, and you may want to investigate the `schedule` clause a bit further, in particular both `dynamic` and `guided` scheduling.

If none of this appeals investigate the OpenMP `task` construct; I don't have time (nor, to be honest, the skill) to offer pseudo-code for that right now.

Finally, if I have misunderstood your question, which often happens, then this answer is probably worthless to you.

Comment: Tank you for your answer ! I already know the `schedule` command but this is only useful if the number of time `foo` need to be lunched is big (namely `N>>number_of_threads`). If it's the case then on average all the threads should stop at the same time. But in my case `N~number_of_threads` and therefore it's not very useful.

Comment: But you gave me an idea... maybe if I change what foo does, and if the `for` loop stops when the convergence criteria has been reached, I could find a solution.

Comment: Half the problem here is the chunk size being set to 10.  You should not set the chunk size and instead use the default of 1.

Comment: I posted my solution, if you can have a look and tell me what you think... tkx !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pramga omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait 
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
       //parallel code with foo(i)
    }
    #pragma omp single 
    {
       //serial code
    }
}
```

Let's say N is 5 and there are 4 threads.  The four threads start running and the first thread to finish starts i=4 and the first thread to finish after that enters the single statement.